# Probability - Distribution and distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The distribution of a discrete random variable $X$ is given in the following table:
>
> [image: Table]
>
> (i) Calculate the distribution function $F_X (x)$ of $X$.
>
> (ii) Let $Y = 2X + 4$ and $Z = | X |.$ Represent the distribution of $Y$ and $Z$ in a table.

Here is my attempt:

(i) $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x < -4,\\
1/4&\text{if }-4 \leq x < 0,\\
5/12&\text{if }0 \leq x < 4, \\
2/3&\text{if }4 \leq x < 12, \\
1&\text{if } x \geq 12 \\
\end{cases}$$

(ii)

$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$y$ $\mid$ $-4$$\text{ }$ $-2$ $\text{ }$ $0$ $\text{ }$ $4$

$P_Y(y) \mid $$\frac{1}{4}$$\text{ }$ $\frac{1}{6}$ $\text{ }$ $\frac{1}{4}$ $\text{ }$ $\frac{1}{3}$

$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$\text{ }$$z$ $\mid$ $0$$\text{ }$ $4$ $\text{ }$ $12$

$P_Z(z) \mid $$\frac{1}{6}$$\text{ }$ $\frac{1}{2}$ $\text{ }$ $\frac{1}{3}$

Can you please check my answers and let me know if I solved this correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (ii) is incorrect, assuming you meant "represent the distribution of $Y$ and $Z$ in a table", since you already have $X$ in a table.

The support for $X$ is $\{-4,0,4,12\}$. This means the support for $Y$ will be $\{-4,4,12,28\}$ and the probabilities will be the corresponding $X$ probabilities since the mapping from $X$ to $Y$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Indeed, I calculated $x = \dfrac{y-4}{2}$ and used these values instead of $-4, 4, 12, 28.$ Is the distribution for $Z$ correct? $4$ shouldn't appear two times in its support, right? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think that's probably a typo from whoever wrote it. $Y$ can't take the value of, say, $0$ because that would mean $X=-2$ and $-2$ isn't in the support of $X$. $Z$ looks correct and yes, it shouldn't be there twice. All instances of $-4$ and $4$ for $X$ map to $4$ so $Z$ will be 4 half of the time.